# display currency switcher in without using xml file in magento

Tags: magento, currency

I have used this [link's](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/) code to enable currency switcher in the header. But I want to use only this code:

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="custom-currency-selector"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>
    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

directly in the header without using XML. So what should I write in place of `$this->`?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/ use this.

Comment: @RaviChomal: I think you didn't read my question properly. I already mentioned this and this links uses a xml to configure it. I don't want to use any xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<?php 
$currencyBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency');
if($currencyBlock->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="custom-currency-selector"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>
    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($currencyBlock->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $currencyBlock->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $currencyBlock->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if you don't want to use currency code in header.phtml and want to manage in separate phtml file then you can use below code in header.phtml:

```
 <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

you can find phtml file here: `app/design/frontend/[Current_Package]/[Current_Theme]/template/directory/currency.phtml`

if you still not able to find you can see currency.phtml in here : `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/directory/currency.phtml`

Hope this helps you. All the best!

Comment: I have tested now... it's works :)
please let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: not showing...I'm using it in 1column.phtml page right now.

Comment: your currency may not configure properly... plz confirm!
follow this article: http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-setup-multiple-currency-magento.html

Comment: I have set Base Currency: Singapore Dollar and Default Display Currency: US Dollar and allowed currencies to Singapore Dollar,US Dollar. But still not showing.....cache also cleaned.

Comment: do you have followed this article? http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-setup-multiple-currency-magento.html

Comment: I really very sorry ! I didn't set the `System->Manage Currencies`...thanks a lot it worked.

Answer (score 1):

poles

try below
add then code is header.phtml file

```
   <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: this code will work on magento2? I tried like below, <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml();?>, which is not working

Comment: How can we do in magento2?